How can I get the population variance from a mixed model?
I supposed it is a basic question, but I'm stuckle on it and I can't find the solution.
I have a date base with the slurry dry matter content from different pig production stages (CATEGORY), also, samples were taken by different operators (OP) and in different moments (SEASON). I'm just interested in estimating the mean and variance population of each category.
To address this I have modelled a linear mixed model with a square transformation of the dependent variable. After testing their significance (AIC,BIC), I have included the OP as a random effect, and the CATEGORY and SEASON as fixed effect.
fit <- nlme::lme(sqrt(MS) ~ CATEGORY + SEASON, 
              random= ~ 1|OP, data=dat)

As I can understand, the estimated mean in each CATEGORY is the corresponding LSM of each fixed effect value. However I'm not pretty sure how to estimate the variance of each category. Simplifying, I have read that in a general linear regression the mean square error of the model is used to estimates the variance of the population, but in a mixed model, with some grouping variables I couldn't find any explanation about how to calculate it.
Is it maybe the standard errors of each fixed effect the equivalent to MSE?
summary(fit)

Fixed effects:  sqrt(MS) ~ CATEGORY + SEASON 
                          Value Std.Error  DF   t-value p-value
(Intercept)           2.0142552 0.1127073 197 17.871557  0.0000
CATEGORYpiglets      -0.2367893 0.1400533 197 -1.690708  0.0925
CATEGORYsows         -0.8191891 0.1195440 197 -6.852615  0.0000
SEASONspring         -0.0280369 0.02811633 194 -0.997177  0.3199
SEASONsummer         -0.0126275 0.03969934 194 -0.318078  0.7508
SEASONoutom          -0.0884407 0.02879816 194 -3.071054  0.0024

My final goal is to estimate the value of the dry matter content that cover 75% of the population. Can you help me please to solve this doubt? If it is useful, I'm using the nlme package in R.
